# How to write the formula to reverse the columns order in query function for Google Sheets?

Tags: reverse, google-sheets-query, columnsorting

I have a database for employees productivity by date, I created a query function to make a pivot table: first column has employee's supervisor, and the remaining columns are for the dates, however, I want to set those columns from recent date to the oldest.

I found an [article](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/query-function-similar-to-pivot-table/) about reversing columns order 
This is the formula I've used:

```
=ArrayFormula({indirect("Week_Pivot!A1:A"&(transpose(row(index(Week_Pivot!B:B,max(isnumber(Week_Pivot!B:B)*row(Week_Pivot!B:B))))))),query({Indirect("Week_Pivot!B1:"&(transpose(row(index(Week_Pivot!B:B,max(isnumber(Week_Pivot!B:B)*row(Week_Pivot!B:B)))))))&""},ArrayFormula("select Col"&join(",Col",transpose(columns(Week_Pivot!A1:1)+1-row(indirect("A"&columns(Week_Pivot!A1:1)&":A"&2))))))})
```

The previous formula only reverses the headers but shows no data below it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out, I've used the `arrayformula` function:

```
=arrayformula(transpose(ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Raw_Pivot!A:G,"select C,G,E,F,avg(D) where A!='' group by C,G,E,F pivot B order by C",1)),1,false))))
```